# VBA - find multiple strings in column then delete rows

Tags: vba, excel

The following VBA code works great however I want to add more strings to delete

e.g Hotel , Home, Flat etc up to 50 values

Edit- Values located in C column

I've looked into arrays but still can't find a solution

```
Dim Find As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Find = .Range("C:C").Find(what:="House")
Do Until Find Is Nothing
    Find.EntireRow.Delete
    Set Find = .Range("C:C").FindNext
Loop
```

Comment: Where are those 50 values?

Comment: all located in the C column

Comment: I mean "Hotel , Home, Flat etc up to 50 values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the rows in a loop can really slow down your code. Store them in a temp range and then delete it in one go. Also store all the words that you want to find in an array and then loop through it to do a search.

Try this (Untested).

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String
    Dim MyAr
    Dim i As Long
    Dim delRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Add more to the list here separated by "/"
    sString = "Hotel/Home/Flat"

    MyAr = Split(sString, "/")

    With ws
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

            Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(aCell.Row)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(aCell.Row))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not delange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
End Sub
```

The above example is to search for only one word. If you want to find repeats then use [Findnext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

**An Alternative to .Find**

Use Autofilter with the array above. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) link. That will give you a start.

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer. Just a suggestion: If you have not tested the answer it is usually not right to accept an answer :) What if you like what @Daniel has posted ;)