# How to find and highlight all occurrences of multiple strings within the ActiveSheet?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2010

I've found a solution already but the code would be too long. Then i decided to search a way of inserting all the words I want to find and highlight into a single Find Method. I came across some ideas of using Arrays to do so and used these 3 codes to write mine ([this](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/10/30/highlight-all-cells-containing-a-specific-value), [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/610926-find-multiple-values-visual-basic-applications.html), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595189/vba-find-multiple-strings-in-column-then-delete-rows)) but I am a new user of VBA so my final code have a problem, it highlights just the last String of the Array. I think the problem is logic but I don't know the basics of VBA so I have no idea how to correct it.

My actual code:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim fnd As String
Dim MyAr
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range, myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)

fnd = "hugo/vw/osnabrück"

MyAr = Split(fnd, "/")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

        Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=MyAr(i), after:=LastCell)

        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
        End If
Set rng = FoundCell
            Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
                Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
                    Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
                If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
            Loop
    Next i

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End Sub
```

For example with this code I can find and highlight all the "Osnabrück" but it doesn't highlight any Hugo or VW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're only doing the highlight once at the very end of the code, and the last choice in your array happens to be osnabruck.

You need to move

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

just before

```
next i
```

so that it'll do if for each element in the array.

Comment: Agreed, this will solve the problem.  Worth noting: it looks like OP was trying to use `Union` to build a `Range` and do a single highlight at the end.  If so, the problem there is the use of `Set rng=FoundCell` which runs for every `i`.  This would work if it was `Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)`.  The problem is that the first `Union` will fail since `rng is Nothing`.  This could be resolved by wrapping that with `If rng is Nothing Then : Set rng = FoundCell : Else : ...union... : End If`.